# DataTables on an ajax response

Tags: datatables

I'm using the datatable.net script on my site and I have a standard loaded table and everything works as expected.

I also have some additional query filters I use to re-load the table.

Something like this

```
$.get(ajaxurl, save_scope, function(response) {
        table.html(response);
        table.DataTable();
    });
```

The response loads correctly, but the DataTable() function doesn't seem to work at all on the newly loaded table. Is there some type of argument I need to pass that causes the DataTable script to re-apply itself on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you receiving?

Datatable() cannot be applied 2 times to the same table.
One possible solution is first remove the table:

```
   //Delete the datable object first
   table.fnDestroy();

   //reload table content
   table.html(response);

   //create table object
   table.DataTable();
```